# Android Integrate Facebook NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, facebook, sharedpreferences

Basically I am trying to integrate Facebook sharing into my Android project. I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/). And I am currently working on the Facebook login when button onClickListener is triggered:

```
    ivFacebookShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.loginToFacebook(getActivity());
        }
    });
```

And in my another class, I am executing loginToFacebook():

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void loginToFacebook(Activity context) {
    mPrefs = context.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(context, new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                // Function to handle complete event
                // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }

            public void onError(DialogError error) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
            }

        });
    }
}
```

However, I am getting error message as the stacktrace:

```
12-23 13:23:05.938: D/AndroidRuntime(29010): Shutting down VM
12-23 13:23:05.938: W/dalvikvm(29010): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c561f8)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.loginToFacebook(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.java:49)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at nyp.edu.eneighbourhood.EventDetail$3.onClick(EventDetail.java:165)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
12-23 13:23:05.954: E/AndroidRuntime(29010):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 13:23:14.618: I/Process(29010): Sending signal. PID: 29010 SIG: 9
```

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you highlight which line is `AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.java:49` so that we can have a better idea of what might be causing your NPE?

Comment: It's this line: if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

Comment: your `facebook` object is null. initialize it inside your method..

Comment: Might be `facebook=NULL`  at `(!facebook.isSessionValid())`

Comment: OK, so is your `facebook` variable being initialised as in the tutorial? (`facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);`)

Comment: Well, like the others have said it is most likely null when you call the `isSessionValid()` method on it. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on it and debugging? You say you are calling this code "in another class" so it might be that this variable is scoped outside of where the call is made (or that the initialisation happens AFTER this code is called)

Comment: In the tutorial, it appears that this is all happening in the same class, so scoping and timing may be different to the way you have laid out your code.

Comment: I see thanks a lot. I figured out already

Comment: Not a problem. Maybe post your answer so other's can benefit from what you have learned?